# MYSQL: Get Previous Row but on base of Non primary Column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have following data in MYSQL Table: Activity

ID is Primary column

TID is non primary

```
ID          Name    TID

11145       Reg     111
14008       Inn     111
20246       Opp     111 <>
20250       Godk    111 <--
111450      Reg     222
140080      Inn     222
202460      Opp     222 <>
202500      Godk    222 <--
```

I need to fetch only previous row to the row where Name = "Godk". You can see previous column is not always primaryID-1 but can be primaryid-n

**Desired Results**:

```
20246       Opp     111
202460      Opp     222
```

I tried using following but in vein

```
SELECT x.* , MAX(y.ID) as prev, 
FROM Activity x,  
INNER JOIN Activity y 
ON y.TID = x.TID
AND y.ID < x.ID 
where y.Name like '%Godk%'
GROUP 
 BY x.TID
 , x.ID;
```

But i am not getting expected results at all.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @RadimBača: 5.7.9

Answer (score 2):

We can use a correlated subquery to handle this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    TID
FROM Activity a1
WHERE
    (SELECT a2.Name FROM Activity a2
     WHERE a1.TID = a2.TID AND
           a2.ID > a1.ID
     ORDER BY a2.ID
     LIMIT 1) = 'Godk';
```

### Demo

But if you are using MySQL 8+, then the `LEAD` analytic function is a much cleaner way to go:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, TID,
        LEAD(Name, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TID ORDER BY ID) AS lead_name
    FROM Activity
)

SELECT ID, Name, TID
FROM cte
WHERE lead_name = 'Godk';
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, Let me execute in my scenario and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have just small bugs in your solution

```
SELECT MAX(y.ID) as prev, y.TID
FROM Activity x
INNER JOIN Activity y ON y.TID = x.TID AND y.ID < x.ID 
WHERE x.Name like '%Godk%'
GROUP BY y.TID
```

However, this solution does not contain the `Name` attribute. If you need it in the result then use another join for this.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.TID
FROM Activity a
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(y.ID) as id, y.TID
    FROM Activity x
    INNER JOIN Activity y ON y.TID = x.TID AND y.ID < x.ID 
    WHERE x.Name like '%Godk%'
    GROUP BY y.TID
) t ON a.TID = t.TID and 
       a.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me execute in my scenario and get back to you